# Linux/Ubuntu version of Mailwasher?

Tags: server, email

apologies for asking a generalised Linux question (not even flavour/version-specific), but there is a big user base out there, and I want to reach as many people as possible. And because Ubuntu is a common choice for Windows users (aka Newbies like me) moving to Linux, it seems logical to pose a question asking for a "Windows replacement" option.

And yes, I know this question (or one very like it) has been asked before, but answers from 2006 aren't much help.

My question: is there a like for like Linux version of Mailwasher? When I say 'like for like', I mean a graphical program (not a script) that allows me to log into and see the contents of a POP3 mailbox (subject, sender, size) and delete selected items at will while they are on the POP3 server. So I don't have to download them in Thunderbird and then delete them (I've got v. slow broadband :-[ ).

I'm definitely not after an automatic POP3 filter. I can look at an email header and make up my own mind; and if, like Mailwasher, I can look at the content of the email while it's on the POP3 server, so much the better.

KShowmail sounded very promising, but I believe the project was abandoned (?). And back in 2002, there was something called 'Save My Modem', but some of you were probably born more recently; I don't believe it has been developed since 2013.

The default alternative is Mailwasher in WINE: has anyone had any luck with that? I assume you'll still have to pay for the Mailwasher licence...

Before you ask, my ISP does have a webmail option on their site, but I'm hoping for something more generic that doesn't restrict me to their mail server.

I know lots of you will have found ways round this, but Firetrust make a living selling Mailwasher, so clearly lots of people want it. They even do a server based filtering package that runs on Linux;  just no Linux client.

Thanks for reading. I would have added the tags POP3 and 'Mailwasher', but I'm a Newbie so I'm not allowed to.

Cheers

John M.

Comment: Do you mean [Mailwasher Free Edition from this page](https://www.mailwasher.net/)?  Their Server edition (which acts as a mail gateway between the Internet and your Email server) has a web based GUI that works from anywhere.  the Server based package that runs on Linux spins a web interface you can use I believe.  There's no drop-in replacement that you're talking about though.

Comment: Hi Thomas,  I've never seen the server edition/GUI,  so I can't comment,  and I'm not knowledgeable enough about server software to know how it might be installed on a desktop running Ubuntu..  I was certainly after something that runs as a client,  if at all possible (Mailwasher for Windows runs as a client application).

Comment: Are there any chances to change your mailbox access protocol from POP to IMAP? Because what you described Mailwasher does it's just a standard way how mail clients like Thunderbird operate via IMAP. You can view a messages list and delete some messages without downloading them.

Comment: IMAP on a very slowbroadband (like mine and OP) is not always reliable or useable. Short of download headers only and deal from there which OP discounts, the only other possible option is to have a second machine acting as a mail server and let it negotiate a connection constantly to get mail and it is then "instantly" available on the LAN.

Comment: Missed edit : Mailwasher works by downloading headers, inspecting them and filter deleting prior to a full fetch of remaining mail. Which you describe being able to do in OP...  Thunderbird has bayesian spam filters to help. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

Browsing through packages available for installation in Synaptic, I found something called `pop3browser`. From the description:

**Allows one to check a pop3 mailbox before downloading any mail**

pop3browser is intended to delete unwanted (SPAM) mails before downloading via a low-bandwidth connection. This is useful to save time, bandwidth and space.

You may give it a try.

Comment: seems to be a header download and inspect tool from the man pages

Comment: Thank you;  I'll take a look and see if I can work out how to install it...

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comments above,
Mailwasher is a filtering tool working on headers via POP3, for clarity it downloads the headers and works locally, then deleting the full email at the ISP. You cannot access and work on the ISP server directly other than webmail. Firetrust clearly describe how Mailwasher works in their own faqs

Thunderbird can be set for headers only (minimising data transfer), run rules on these and then download what is left ie the functionality you appear to want.

This link should help http://kb.mozillazine.org/Download_only_certain_POP_messages

I appreciate you didn't want to use filters as per your comment on the spam assasin answer, but the reality is that is how the software you want to install is actually functioning - and the tool is built into many mail clients

Hope this helps

Comment: In answer to @Crighton,  I take your point entirely.  But Thunderbird can't remove entire messages from the POP3 mailbox if it's only set to download the headers,  unless I'm missing something.  Mailwasher doesn't (by default) use any filters - it just offers a simple point and shoot system.  Like I said,  a lot of people seem willing to pay for it,  so I'm still surprised that no-one stepped up to take KShowmail forward.  Re. filters,  there is no message filtering system in the world,  no matter how clever,  that won't at some point block a 'safe' message,  or allow an 'unsafe' message.

Answer (score 0):

**SpamAssassin.**

Use this program to "Unspam" your mailbox(es).

The program can be integrated with the mail server to automatically filter all mail for a site.

It can also be run by individual users on their own mailbox and integrates with several mail programs.

SpamAssassin is highly configurable; if used as a system-wide filter it can still be configured to support per-user preferences.

**POPFile**

Classifies email into categories you define.

It can sort into spam and not spam or into any number of categories you like.

The classification is done using a naïve Bayes algorithm. In other words, POPFile uses statistics to track which words are likely to appear in which messages.

This means that POPFile will adapt to the kind of mail you receive and needs to be trained. Out of the box, it doesnt know anything about spam or how messages from your mother differ from those your friends send you.

However, if you train it, it will soon learn how to tell these different kinds of messages apart.

Comment: Do these programs allow the user to view their inbox on the ISP prior to downloading the mail to the local machine?

Comment: Organic Marble has asked exactly the question I would have.  I thin Spam Assassin is a message filtering package,  which (as I said) is what I don't want.